# Android - Save an rtsp (h264) stream to mp4 file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mp4, android-mediarecorder

I am working on a project where I need to

1. Read input H.264 encoded stream from an IPCamera  - I am able to fetch this in through an rtsp url like rtsp://192.168.1.83:8001/
2. Display the IPCamera stream - This I am able to do using the

---

```
final VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view_h264);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(getApplicationContext());
        vv.setVideoURI(video);
        vv.setMediaController(mc);
        vv.requestFocus();
        vv.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                vv.start();
            }
        });
```

---

1. Now I want to record this stream to an MP4 file. This is where I am stuck and I am considering the following options

a) MediaRecorder - Based on my google searches I believe for this class the input can only from a device camera. Is there a way to tweak this where I can provide an input from rtsp stream ?

b) MediaCodec API - 4.1 onwards Android has released this low level API with and MediaExtractor and MediaCodec. For this option I think an rtsp stream cannot be used in the following snippet

```
final String STREAM_URL = "rtsp://192.168.1.83:8001/";
MediaExtractor mediaExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
mediaExtractor.setDataSource(STREAM_URL); // I get an exception 04-28 18:30:18.914: E/AndroidRuntime(8140): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to instantiate extractor.
```

c) Can I do a read from the url and store it like a file. How to I convert this stream to an MP4 file ? Any code snippet will be really helpful.

I had also tried to use FFMPEG but the performance was so poor that I dropped this option.

Any inputs on the above three options or any other additional option which I can consider will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !!

Comment: Do you wish to display and record into the file simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to display and record simultaneously. I am able to manage the display part, but recording part is where I am stuck.

Comment: @maxkart Have you found any solution for your problem, I have same problem like you have

If you found any solution then give the answer of your question in details.

I appreciate if you do..
Thanks in advanced

Comment: Nope unfortunately !! I was't able to achieve the recording bit.

Comment: Trying to the do something very similar. 6 years later and things haven't improved a whole lot. We ended up going with FFmpeg but also ran into some packet loss with UDP and some missed frames with TCP. Is that what kind of poor performance you were seeing as well?

Answer (score 1):

It is true that `MediaRecorder` doesn't have any support for handling direct streaming content. From a frameworks perspective, there are parser objects as in `MediaExtractor` and codec objects like `MediaCodec`, but not writer abstractions (yet).

In `AOSP`, `recordVideo` is a command line utility aimed for a simple file based recording. As part of the implementation, an encoder is created and passed to the `MPEG4Writer` as observed [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/recordvideo.cpp#293). You could potentially reuse this code and try to write the incoming stream into the file directly.

For this you could model your streaming input as a `MediaSource` and pass it to the writer directly. You would have to setup certain basic `metaData` from the streaming source and pass it to the downstream writer. You may not require to create a new `MediaRecorder`, if you could model the input source directly.

Comment: Ganesh - Thanks for your response. Are you suggesting that a  a JNI code could be written where I use the MPEG4Writer ? Also I was wondering if I could use recordVideo utility directly by passing a file. Can you point me to any other documentation on recordVideo ? Thanks

Comment: @maxkart.. Yes, you could consider modifying the JNI code to support the `MPEG4Writer` object. The current `recordVideo` utility doesn't support a file input, but a dummy source. However, the same can easily be extended to support a file source, to read `YUV` frames from file, encode the same and store into a `mp4` file.

Answer (score 1):

Got the exact same problem over here. FFmpeg solves the problem and seems very efficient to me but it is hardware dependent, it need to be compiled for the specific arm version of each device's cpu.

Another approach  jcodec (http://jcodec.org/)  but haven't yet figured out how to save a rtsp stream with it. It is a purely java library, but there isn't much documentation available.

Please tell me if you figure out a way of doing it.

Comment: Nope unfortunately !! I was't able to achieve the recording bit.